# Convert UTC Time with offset to LocalTime

Tags: jodatime, localtime

I am using joda 2.7, I want to convert

```
      UTC Time= 09:30:10-06:00
   to Local Time= 03:30:10
         and
      UTC Time=10:45:00+07:30
   to Local Time = 18:15:00
```

I tried different formats both joda's and my own and methods to handle the offset part, but I am not able to get the required output. What is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ssZ");
String utcTime = "09:30:10-06:00";
DateTime localTime = fmt.parseDateTime(utcTime);
String localTimeString = localTime.toString("HH:mm:ss");
```

This will convert it to your local time, according to your default timezone (do `System.out.println(DateTimeZone.getDefault())` to check what's your default timezone).

If you want to convert to a different timezone, you need to do something like:

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(/*DateTimeZone you want*/);
```

In your specific cases, to get the output you want, you just need to use the timezone in which you have the desired outputs:

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-12));

String utcTime = "09:30:10-06:00";
DateTime localTime = fmt.parseDateTime(utcTime);
System.out.println(localTime.toString("HH:mm:ss"));

utcTime = "10:45:00+07:30";
localTime = fmt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(15)).parseDateTime(utcTime);
System.out.println(localTime.toString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Output is:

```java
03:30:10
18:15:00
```

Comment: ok when I tried this, the time I get is 08:30:10, is that correct? I want the time to be 03:30:10

Comment: that works, how do you calculate offset hours?, I mean if I get any time with any offset how can I generalize the select an offset step.

Comment: is it , + or- (2*offset time)?

Comment: I think it's hard to generalize from only these 2 examples. In the first, you're converting from GMT -6 to GMT -12, or 6 hours behind. In the second, you're converting from GMT +7:30 to GMT +15 (7,5 hours ahead). You need to get all the possible cases and try to generalize and get a formula for them (if possible), or handle each case individually, according to what you need.
"Doubling" the current offset works for these 2 cases, but would it work for all the cases you want? (I'm assuming that you might have more different cases; if not, then the code above should be enough)

Comment: What package of DateTimeFormatter are you using? java.time.format. DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime does not exist - you might use org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter? should be specified in the answer.